2024 WeAreDevelopers Event Summary
Update August 20, 2024
The video of Prashanth's presentation at We Are Developers is now available. I have linked it at the end of the question.

Earlier today, Prashanth Chandrasekar, CEO of Stack Overflow, presented at the 2024 WeAreDevelopers World Congress in Berlin. A key takeaway is that Community is and will always be at the center of everything we do. The community and shared knowledge on the platform are irreplaceable.
Prashanth shared some of the community product initiatives that we’ve been focused on lately, including:

The return of Staging Ground
The new version of Stack Overflow Jobs
The recent changes we made to Data Dumps access to allow them to still be accessible by the majority of users while restricting access to those using them for commercial purposes.

Prashanth also shared some of the upcoming initiatives we’re focusing on, both the Teams product and the Stack Exchange Network. This included:

Enterprise Search on our Teams product
A GitHub extension to direct users to Stack Overflow to ask their questions there if they aren’t finding the solution they need using CoPilot.

These new initiatives are slated for late 2024 and early 2025. We’ll share more information on the blog about Enterprise Search for Teams, and we’ll share more information on Meta Stack Overflow about the GitHub extension.
Here is the link to the video of the presentation.

I was going to ask how the company can say the "Community is and will always be at the center of everything we do" when the same community is showing so much dissent against your "changes", especially the " recent changes we made to Data Dumps access to allow them to still be accessible by the majority of users while restricting access to those using them for commercial purposes" (at least be honest there: the issue is that you want to be the only ones using them for commercial purposes). Then I noticed that technically the line does not imply working for the community interest.

"The recent changes we made to Data Dumps access to allow them to still be accessible by the majority of users while restricting access to those using them for commercial purposes." - do you [SE] not hear the self-conflicting statements you [SE] are making, or do you [SE] actually believe this? You [SE] are heavily restricting it and making it significantly harder for non-commercial users to use, without actually doing anything about AI companies (at least not in a way that's legal, but that's a tangent for lawyers to solve when you get sued over it)

Since you're saying that community is at the center of everything you do let's talk about the recent changes made to Data Dumps access, the community has raised several concerns around that and there's generally been complete silence (or you can say the community has been completely ignored) from the company on those and it's nearly been a week since then, is this what "community being at the center of everything we do" means?

"The community and shared knowledge on the platform are irreplaceable." - this statement is blatantly incompatible with your [SE's] data dump changes; those changes make it significantly harder to archive the data, which means that if the company goes down or kills the platform abruptly, new data is much more likely to be irrecoverably gone. If we actually mattered, you [SE] wouldn't actively sabotage archival efforts

ohhhhhh!!!!! The changes to the Data Dump were posted on Friday, because you needed to rush out the announcement so that Prashanth could brag about it at a conference! That makes more sense now.  At least you remembered to tell Meta first.

Will/can this post be featured, possibly once a video link is added?

Please, get Prashanth to define community because I'm 100% confident it does not match the communities definition when he hasn't spoken to it in over 3.5 years.

Whomever those "developers" are, they're obviously not avid SO users (although I suppose eggs and vegetables have been quite pricey around here lately).

"If you'd like to see the full talk" -- to be honest, I'd rather watch the kettle boil. The SNR of that will probably be better. Franky, I don't even understand how you can post this -- surely you must be aware of how much that has to do with the reality. And spreading lies is just as bad as originating them.

Standing by, waiting for you to demonstrate you give the slightest damn about the community "at the center of everything you do".

@Basic Just don't hold your breath while doing so ;)

"A key takeaway is that Community is and will always be at the center of everything we do."
This is gaslighting. The company has been myopically focused on Stack Overflow for Teams being a key revenue stream. The Community being the center is a Company core value that is still listed, but was abandoned long ago.
The new version of Stack Overflow Jobs
This is just white-labeled Indeed. I still haven't figured out what "special sauce" Stack Overflow adds to this other than their logo. Is there something that I'm missing?
The recent changes we made to Data Dumps access to allow them to still be accessible by the majority of users while restricting access to those using them for commercial purposes.
I'm sorry, but breaching the CC BY-SA license by restricting commercial use only serves to further erode Community trust in the Company.
If you'd like to see the full talk...
No thanks.

Practically they've sort of lost interest in teams, and are myopically chasing AI, without the slightest clue of what they want to do with it, or the sentiments of the community about it.

Yeah, but even with The Great AI Chase, they haven't shipped any features to the public network. As far as I know, they're primarily targeting Teams with deliverables. So even while chasing AI, they're still focused on Teams. You'll notice the URL for OverflowAI has /teams/ in the middle: https://stackoverflow.co/teams/ai/ and it shows it is a feature for Teams Enterprise only.

The GenAI SE was force-started one year ago to lead SE into the shiny new AI future. It has all of 326 questions, less than one a day. In that time, Physics SE has over 15,000 questions.

@AMtwo here is what they mostly want to with AI: sell data dump to AI companies. That requires no skills, data is already there,  authors (SE users) keep expanding it, and there are already plenty of data customers (SE data dump is part of many LLM training sets). The only "work" that SE Inc. has to do is changing the license of the SE data dump. The stakes: Reddit user content being sold to AI company in $60M/year deal. Anything else that SE does about AI is peanuts in comparison, from a financial standpoint.

I start to wonder if SE developer made some magic code that makes your posts and comments disappear from staff view, otherwise can't explain why not a single post or comment of yours ever got a reply from staff. That's the worst treatment: treat one as if they just don't exist.

@ShadowWizard -- that'd be a neat feature. But to be fair, it's hard for anyone to speak when they are wearing a muzzle

The first argument doesn't seem entirely true, since SO for teams is free up to 50 users it can be said it provides a valuable free service to small communities. Many of the impactful open-source projects I follow have less than 50 regular contributors so it's perfectly suitable to the needs of most teams.

@bad_coder The key words are "at the center" and "of everything" -- They don't care about the larger public platform community (other than maybe content generation for their LLM marketplace, now, maybe). As former staff, I'm really confident that the free tier is a good product that they currently offer--but it's hardly at the center to their strategy.

@AMtwo I don't care so much for the buzzwords/catchphrases because most companies have "ethics" in their "core values" but if you interview management/administration you'll notice most of them don't even know what the word means, or how it's applied. In this place I've usually seen the "blame game" being pointed towards the company but boy oh boy could I point out so many mods and regulars who are clueless about fostering a respectful humane environment - and the later are vocal, and they garner votes, and they're successful at suppressing differing views. You get the community you foster.

@bad_coder Part of improving the community is calling out the hypocrisy though.  And if I take their values seriously.... (well, as an employee, I probably would get targeted for a layoff...hohoho) then I'm going to keep hammering the Company on their double-speak, in the hope of them changing. Because you're right--they do get the community that they foster.

It will be short.

Community is and will always be at the center of everything we do

Sorry, but your recent actions tell otherwise.

Shadow Wizard hit the nail on the head, but I'd like to elaborate.
You say that "Community is and will always be at the center of everything we do". However, of the three highlights, only one has been positively received by the community, and that's after it was put on hold for a while.
The new version of Stack Overflow Jobs isn't really a returning feature. It's a reskinned search of Indeed that is plagued with bugs around being able to, among other things, search and filter for jobs. It also doesn't have features, such as the Developer Story, that made the original SO Jobs unique for job seekers.
The changes to the data dump are a very negatively scored question with many unanswered questions from the community, with the open questions around enforcement, licensing, ease of access, and trust.
How can community be at the center of everything when you aren't listening to the concerns of the community and responding to those concerns and other questions in a timely manner?

I'm somewhat underwhelmed.
The return of the Staging Ground is literally the unshelving of a shelved, very popular idea that, while Stack Overflow Jobs is pretty much a less interesting revival of an old, sunset product lacking most of what stopped it from being yet another job site - assuming that it becomes more than a thin wrapper for Indeed.

A GitHub extension to direct users to Stack Overflow to ask their questions here if they aren’t finding the solution they need using CoPilot.

I'm not a dev, but wouldn't you use Stack Overflow if you needed an answer, and why would you ever want to be the second place someone looks for answers?
The recent changes to the data dump access is a slightly neutered version of the 'idea' that resulted in a strike, and honestly, I'd back another strike if it came to it.
Let's talk instead about

A key takeaway is that Community is and will always be at the center of everything we do. The community and shared knowledge on the platform are irreplaceable.

We were told the company would put 10% of its resources into AI for... no real benefit, and we lost a lot more than that
The return of the Staging Ground isn't a triumph, it's a small bright spark in an otherwise dreary outlook for us, and the company hasn't really shown the community to be the center of what we do. You had a good plan, and lacked the attention span to see it through. While its back in some fashion, the manner in which it happened shows it wasn't a priority.
In the past year, we've had more folks who were active on the community downsized in some teams than they have active on the staff now  Former staff who acted as a bridge between the community and company left - potentially directly due to - the staging ground being shelved the last time. These people were community, and they weren't so much replaced, as dropped. We're not likely to find another Cat, V2Blast, Nicolas or many of the other community managers we lost over the years, and the pool of optimists who believe they can make a difference isn't infinite. The company has a clear disconnect from the community
This has been an ongoing antipattern for many years. The company acts against our interests and theirs, fails in their grand plans, and somehow expects us to trust them when they do either the bare minimum, or the exact same thing again with minor changes.
I fear for my community - while my little corners of the network do alright, a good amount of it is due to the work of the moderator teams. We listen, we earn trust, we engage, but a big enough mistake on the company's side could ruin what we've built. I've seen places lose a lot of familiar faces and I don't really see the same level of engagement we used to. I said years ago that the smaller communities didn't get any love, and I think the bigger ones feel it too.
SE isn't a welcoming place for many of us, and the close links between community and staff we once had get more and more tenuous. I quit as a moderator on this site in protest in October 2023, and the company has literally made zero progress in many aspects. We see neither actions aimed at improving trust or community health nor any clear investments in the community. I'd note that our data is literally the next revenue stream, and folks who post quality content leaving would hurt the value of that substantially.
From the perspective of a core community member, over the years we've seen a company that's not held up to its social contract, often ending up being a hostile environment for community members who are staff, lack of care for the health of communities, and a dwindling level of trust.
We need data dumps the company does not control precisely because the company constantly keeps breaking our trust. Maybe some day things will hit a tipping point and some scrappy upstart will end up doing to SE what SE did to the hyphen site.
The company has lacked long term vision for a very long time, and it feels like the folks in management don't want to run a healthy community run social software site - they want a SaaS business where people pay money and don't ask questions.
Unfortunately that's kind of hard over a decade of broken promises and alienating the core community.
I don't want to see the talk. I want to see action. I want to see healthy communities, respect for our needs and for the company and its management to take a good hard look at the mistakes they have made over the last decade and change. Frankly outside the inevitable downsizing of line staff, I feel like the current initiatives failing would be potentially positive for the community if it made management realise things were going wrong. I guess I'm an optimist - since I'm sure folks will tell me nothing will change, and we'll just go through another cycle
I want to be able to work with staff I know for the good of my community, see community members step up to work at Stack Exchange and know they're not going to get the chop the next time the current or past CEO doesn't make their numbers. The company has not valued your best advocates to the community, and we lost ours.
For that matter I'd like to know the teams I directly work with have sufficient resources to do their jobs and are able to attract the people they need from within and outside the community. I've complained about the community team being understaffed a few times and honestly, I'm worried the next time there's a failure elsewhere in the business we'd lose more people we can't afford to. I'd love more direct staff engagement too, but I'd start with knowing that the people on the back end have what they need. The company has historically shown they're very happy to cut down some teams to the bone (we had 4 community managers at one point).
(Full disclosure - I applied to be community manager about 4 times before changing requirements made it impossible. I'd note competition and excitement within the community got less and less, and you'd be lucky to find anyone within the community if you opened up a role.)
I was asked at a recentish job interview about what I did as a moderator on the network. I like what I do, but I do feel like a lot of it was holding things together and keeping folks informed of what was going on. (I was vaguer than I liked.) I'd like to say I was reassuring them - but I need reassurance myself. What I couldn't do was talk about how SE was a shining example of social responsibility and great ties between community and commercial interests... because it isn't.
So, stop saying the community is the center of what you do. Make it so. Show the community is the center of what you do by listening and understanding our needs and building trust before demanding it.
Stop to listen to the sentiment about AI (mostly negative), and try to understand why people are hostile to it. If you can't win over the community to it - most of these initiatives will fail.
I'd note the title of Prashanth's talk was "The future of the internet and the open web." Do stop and consider how the current way that data dump access is structured is the opposite. I grew up on the open web - I missed the walled garden era, and the diversity the web had then. Many current actions - nagging about logins and closing off the data dumps is the exact opposite of what the open web is.
Make the network something people care about again - look at things like community applications and hires for open roles. Have people who are good at actually communicating with the community and can give and get real, unfiltered feedback.
Act on this feedback, not what you want to believe is right - the current obsession with AI is just the latest in the company focusing on something other than the network, to our detriment.
If you read all this way, GG. Gimme a ping somewhere to let me know :D 

"I'd back another strike if it came to it." --- Seconded.

FWIW, I think Staff have been asked not to engage on the Data Dump discussion without permission from Senior Leadership. I'm sure the same goes for this question. It's impossible to square that with the declaration that "Community is and will always be at the center of everything we do"

Your sentiments expressed here resonate a lot with me; the latest data dump debacle is the first thing that's really made me, personally, feel deeply frustrated, but on the whole I just feel tired and disappointed. It feels clear to me that there are individuals at the company who want to bridge the rift that's been created, but the ship as a whole is sailing farther and farther away. It feels like the further it goes, the more drastic a shift rectifying it would require, and the less likely that very shift becomes. It just makes me sad :(

@AMtwo You were a developer, not a CM at SE, but did you (plural) also receive such specific instructions not to engage with the community in certain topics, or did you limit yourself (as you said elsewhere on MSE) out of fear for repercussions?

@AndreasmovedtoCodidact Both... While I was an Engineer at Stack, I limited my posts & responses on MSE to specific maintenance/outages that I was directly involved in. I preferred not to engage otherwise because it is possible to get your wrist metaphorically slapped for saying the wrong thing/too much. In addition to that, there we several occasions where we were instructed to specifically not comment on the Meta post.

@AndreasmovedtoCodidact In fact, last June (after I was laid off, and it became public that the Data Dump had been turned off), I asked several former coworkers for an update with regard to getting the Data Dump re-enabled---they each informed me that they had been told by Senior Leadership not to comment publicly.   You know...13 months ago...when the Company lied to us, promising they would leave the Data Dumps on until they had build "guardrails".

@AMtwo Ah, that’s interesting. Thanks for the responses, and for your activity here. Your insights on the matters are valuable, and it’s healthy for the community to have facts instead of having to base so much on interpretations, guesses and assumptions. Personally, in one way, it’s nice to have a bunch of my assumptions and interpretations confirmed, but on the other hand, it’s sad that the situation is like this. At least I’m happy we need to argue less about what’s true, and what’s just an assumption.

@AndreasmovedtoCodidact traditionally staff from across the network engaged with the community - that AMtwo was a DBA is ... vaguely irrelevant. I can't imagine the community is at the center of everything they do if staff don't engage the community nor if things are being kept from the community.

That's to say I think its a good idea to encourage staff across the company to engage freely and, frankly for upper management to learn to trust that the community's got the network's best interests in heart, even if they don't like what they hear.

@JourneymanGeek It’s relevant in terms of what instructions he’d have received from the leadership. With different roles, comes different instructions. Of course, I agree that staff from all parts of the company should engage with the community, but it’s first and foremost the role of community managers, so especially these days, I imagine the company giving different instructions. If their goal is to limit communication, it’s easier to give a blanket ban to everybody not a CM, and then more detailed ones to CMs.

Missing a period (.) at the end of the sentence, but I understand now. Thanks!


The recent changes we made to Data Dumps access to allow them to still be accessible by the majority of users while restricting access to those using them for commercial purposes.

This is of course 100% against the existing CC BY-SA license, but I'd also like to point out that in the linked post, you claimed:

this is primarily only a change in location for where the data dump is accessed.

which is grossly misleading, since you now admit the main change is restricting access to people using the dumps for commercial purposes (and not some data host change, which you tried to use to hide the license change). And "restricting access" is an euphemism for charging $$$ for the access.
Ironically, your disingenuous actions make it even more critical to have a CC BY-SA data dump.


A key takeaway is that Community is and will always be at the center
of everything we do. The community and shared knowledge on the
platform are irreplaceable.

Right now CEO and the company are at open war with the community and are doing everything in their power to destroy the very little trust that was left (if any) after previous decision debacles.
Community is falling apart left and right. More and more core users, the ones that are providing valuable content in answers (questions without answers are useless), are losing their interest in participating and some are already long gone.
You will have no new content to sell for your precocious AI partnerships, unless you are fine with selling AI generated crap which we still have pouring in abundance.
It seems like company is establishing a tradition where just before WeAreDevelopers conference community will be given a hard, almost unrecoverable blow, after which CEO will cheerfully make his presentation as if nothing is happening.
How long do you think there will be a community if the company continues pulling totally nonsensical moves out of their hats?
Stack Overflow has not yet recovered from the last year's strike, and just as we have started to slowly make some progress in handling accumulated flags (which would still take us months, if not years, to work through) and as some striking moderators started to come back and increase their activities, they are now again contemplating about leaving and overall morale is far from good.
If you lose SO moderators, and you are on the verge of that happening, the few ones that may remain will be nowhere near enough to handle even newly raised flags. And you will not be able to solve that with another round of elections as you won't be able to replace all moderators that will either leave or significantly reduce their  activity.
And this time there will be no strike and no warning, it will be just people (mods and regular users) leaving for good.
If you want to reverse the course (and pray this is possible now), just abandon the idea that data dumps are a problem and revert to old process. Anything less will not end up good. And for God's sake (I am an atheist, but only God can help us now) start listening to what moderators are telling you before you make next detrimental move.

Indeed, I agree: this time looks like there isn't even going to be a strike, as the users realized the bitter truth: it won't help. Instead, I expect many to just leave silently or stop contributing. Personally I'm still not sure, and since I'm active only here, might still do it.

@ShadowWizard There is a good reason why I never changed my name here on Meta back to my own ;)
